# A conceptual question on indefinite integrals

Tags: calculus

Since the two functions $x\mapsto \frac{x^2-x}{x}$ and $x\mapsto x-1$ are different (the former is not defined at $x=0$ whereas the latter is), then is the following work incorrect?
$\int \frac{x^2-x}{x}\,dx = \int (x-1) dx = \frac{1}{2}x^2 - x + C$
The result says that $x\mapsto  \frac{1}{2}x^2 - x + C$ is the family of antiderivatives of the function $x\mapsto\frac{x^2-x}{x}$, which is incorrect for the above reason.
Any enlightenment? What is the (or is there a) correct way to compute $\int \frac{x^2-x}{x}\,dx$? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is incorrect, because any function of the type$$x\mapsto\begin{cases}\frac12x^2-x+C_1&\text{ if }x>0\\\frac12x^2-x+C_2&\text{ if }x<0\end{cases}$$will be an antiderivative of your function. Since the domain consists of the union of two disjoint intervals, you can take an arbitrary constan on each of them

Comment: Thanks. But then what about, e.g., $\int \frac{1}{x^2} dx$? Since the domain of the integrand is also the union of two disjoint intervals, would it be incorrect to say that the integral equals to $-\frac{1}{x}+C$?

Comment: That answer is correct but, as in my answer, it doesn't provide **all** antiderivatives of $\frac1{x^2}$.

Comment: OK, so whenever we are doing usual indefinite integral computations, are we assuming locality (i.e., that the integrand is defined only over an interval containing no singularities)? Most books just say $\int\frac{1}{x^2}dx=-\frac{1}{x}+C$ without saying that $C$ may depend on where we are.